# Elasticsearch hot-backup strategies

Tags: backup, elasticsearch

It would be interesting if someone could share his best 'hot-backup' strategies for `ElasticSearch`.

Also, feel free to share tools and libraries related to this problem and can help.

**Updated:**
Thank you @javanna for your response, it's quite complete and provides good direction for further actions.

I also did a small research and found some articles/discussions which can help if somebody has an interest.

- [Elasticsearch backup strategies](http://www.dark.ca/2011/11/22/elasticsearch-backup-strategies/)
- [Backup/restore Elasticsearch index](http://tech.superhappykittymeow.com/?p=296) and [related snippet on github:gist](https://gist.github.com/1939828)
- [Elastic Search Backup and Recovery](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Elastic-Search-Backup-and-Recovery-td4020442.html) discussion (check the comment of Paul Smith, also he shared a usefull link to his [tool for verifying indexes](https://github.com/Aconex/scrutineer) )

**Update:** Elasticsearch 1.0 have an "official" backup solution - [Snapshot/Restore API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-snapshots.html) and this is the only right way to it now. ElasticSearch will identify master shards and take care about consistency. The backup is going to be done incrementally, so you will be able to do it very fast and as often as you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replicas are a sort of backup, and elasticsearch never allocates one on the same node where the original primary shard is. But then there is still the risk of losing data depending on how many shards, replicas and nodes you have in your cluster.

I would look at the [Gateway](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/gateway/) module, through which you can save the index and the cluster metadata. There are different type of gateway. I'd look at the [Shared FS](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/gateway/fs/) for example, which allows you to copy the index and the metadata to a file system which is shared between all your nodes. You can also manually start a snapshot through the [Gateway Snapshot API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-gateway-snapshot/).

Also, you can make a copy of the data directory (on every node) once you disabled flush through the [index.translog.disable_flush index setting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings/). That way you would make sure that no lucene commit will be issued while you're copying. After you made the copy you need to enable flush again.

**UPDATE**

All the gateway types except for the local one have been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Elasticsearch 1.0 will be released with a better backup solution.

Comment: 'The S3 gateway is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use the local gateway instead.' http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/gateway/s3/

Answer (score -4):

So this goes against how ElasticSearch works, but I'd consider having 2 separate ElasticSearch instances that are not aware of each other. In your app code, every command gets sent to both instances. If a command fails for 1 instance, retry that command 1 minute later, and keep retrying. Now you can keep 1 of the instances as a hot-backup, or you can even use it to improve performance by load balancing the queries between the 2 instances.

The reason why I don't like setting up replicas in ElasticSearch is it's a pain to configure which node gets which replica, and if you want to rearrange the organization in the future, you basically have to go through a ton of hoops. ElasticSearch does a ton of rebalancing behind the scenes, and tries to do everything for you. Which can be good.. if you have powerful servers and don't care what gets what.. but can be a pain otherwise.